# Is Google TagManager using gzip compression when transferring data?

Tags: android, google-analytics, gzip, google-play-services, google-tag-manager

I am working on an Android app that tracks usage through Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager through Google Play Services. 
Logging is done through the com.google.android.gms.tagmanager package.

Now, there is a requirement to never transfer more user probe data than X kB per month, and I have a good idea about how much space each measurement takes encoded into "googlish" data format. The thing is that I don't know is how much traffic this probe data will result in since that would depend on knowing data packaging details, whether GZIP compression is used when transferring data etc. Neither do I know how to measure this traffic in a good way since the data is handled by Play Services, and most likely not visible in the app's data usage.

Does anyone know how I can figure out and predict the amount of data being sent over the data connection for a given amount of Tag Manager probe data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google Play service will batch hits together and gzip compress them. Later versions of the SDK will also batch and compress the traffic when the data is dispatched from the app process itself.

Comment: Great, thanks! Any idea how the amount of app generated data traffic can be measured?